# How to use angular functions in kendo templates

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, kendo-ui

I'm currently working with AngularJS and Kendo UI.
I have a kendo grid with edit buttons.
The edit template is a custom popup which causes my problem:

My objects have a foreign key "CategoryID",
when I click the edit button I want to show a dropdown with all of the categories and the current category selected.
I have those categories available in my Angular scope, but the template doesn't seem to support angular databinding like: ng-model and ng-options.
So I get an empty dropdown.

I don't like to use al kinds of hard-coded kendo tags like "data-type", "data-role" and "data-bind".

I would love to be able to activate the angular binding, so I will be able to use ng attributes. 
Or, if anyone has a good alternative in how to achieve a nice dropdown in the kendo template, please let me know!